# For loop causes exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to draw an animation with text as described in code in draw() method.

```
    if (condition)
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                            canvas.drawText("miss", (float) chibi1.getX(), (float) chibi1.getY()-j, pt.pBlack);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }).start();
```

It works fine until probably it reaches the last iteration.

Error looks like this:

```
2019-11-30 13:02:17.295 16294-16383/pl.jawegiel.grarpg.pl.jawegiel.grarpg A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 16383 (Thread-36), pid 16294 (jawegiel.grarpg) 2019-11-30 13:02:17.361 16414-16414/? A/DEBUG: pid: 16294, tid: 16383, name: Thread-36  >>> pl.jawegiel.grarpg.pl.jawegiel.grarpg <<< 2019-11-30 13:02:17.676 16414-16414/? E/crash_dump64: Normal dump:pl.jawegiel.grarpg.pl.jawegiel.grarpg 2019-11-30 13:02:17.727 1393-1832/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '574dd1 pl.jawegiel.grarpg.pl.jawegiel.grarpg/pl.jawegiel.grarpg.activities.Gra (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! 2019-11-30 13:02:17.750 1393-1832/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6cb9262 pl.jawegiel.grarpg.pl.jawegiel.grarpg/pl.jawegiel.grarpg.activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! 2019-11-30 13:02:17.751 814-814/? E/ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = pl.jawegiel.grarpg.pl.jawegiel.grarpg pid = 0 2019-11-30 13:02:17.928 1393-1475/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.sonymobile.crashmonitorsystemservice.DIR_UPDATED from system 1393:system/1000 pkg android
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:21850)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:22459)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:22601)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1224)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1196)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextWrapper.java:525)
        at com.sonymobile.crashmonitor.system.service.DumpfileObserver.onEvent(DumpfileObserver.java:32)
        at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent(FileObserver.java:123)
        at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
        at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:86)
```

Why it happens and what to change?

Comment: You have two nested `for` loops with same initializer i.e. `i`, try changing one of them to some other name.

Comment: Thanks but error did not disappear

Comment: Shouldn't this `chibi1.getY()-i` be `chibi1.getY()-j` now ?

Comment: You are right but it doesn't change anything with error

Comment: I don't know your whole codebase, but my guess is that objects used inside the thread are also accessed or modified in main thread. You might have to use a synchronization mechanism or just wait until thread is done before continuing in the main thread. A quick test is to call  thread.join(). Thread th = new Thread...; th.start(); th.join();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not execute methods on a `View` canvas from a thread other than the UI (main) thread. In addition, you may not retain a reference to `canvas` after `onDraw()` has returned; those objects are frequently changed/recycled on the native side shortly after the draw pass is complete. You will probably notice that the next time `onDraw()` is called, it is passed a completely different `Canvas` object.

Furthermore, the `Canvas` object is not threadsafe, as far as I'm aware. I suspect your `chibi1` (whatever that is) is also not threadsafe, and it is also being accessed in a dangerous way.

Frankly, I'm surprised your loop managed to make it more than 1 iteration without a SIGSEGV.

Solution: Only do animations from the UI thread. Break apart your loop, and turn it into a [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which will keep track of where you want to draw.

For instance:

```
class MyViewClass extends View
{

    ...
    private int mJ = 0;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
    {
        ...
        if(mJ <= 100)
        {
            canvas.drawText("miss", (float) chibi1.getX(), (float) chibi1.getY()-mJ, pt.pBlack);
            mJ++;
            invalidate();    //Prompt an immediate re-draw
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```